# Проблема с ViewPager на Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Буду благодарен если укажете ссылку на нужную информацию, приложение вылетает только на Android 5.0 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(при дебагинге ошибка указывает на индикатор viewpager)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внутри viepagera ничего особенного только картинка в фрагменте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

B только на Android 5.0 вылетает приложение, на других платформах работает и запускается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лог с ошибкой текстом приведите.

Comment: лог с ошибкой указывает на первый рисунок обычный фрагмент сам никак не могу понять в дело